# CamaraX mp4 Video Recording record 3gp video only?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

I am trying to record a video using CameraX version `1.0.0-beta12` Here is the code portion to record a video

```
getVideoCapture()?.startRecording(
    mVideoFileSaver.getNewVideoOutputFileOptions(
        contentResolver
    ), ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), mVideoFileSaveListener
)
```

And here is the output options

```
fun getNewVideoOutputFileOptions(resolver: ContentResolver): VideoCapture.OutputFileOptions {
    val videoFileName = "video_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "_video.mp4"
    val contentValues = ContentValues()
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4")
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, videoFileName)
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, videoFileName)
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis())
    }
    return VideoCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(
        resolver,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues
    ).build()
}
```

Now after getting the video in the Gallery, I found that the video file name is .3gp. Could anyone tell me how to record mp4 file using CameraX?

Comment: Did you try on different devices?

Comment: @androidcodehunter have you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
val fileOutputOptions = FileOutputOptions.Builder(File).build()

activeRecording = videoCapture.output.prepareRecording(this, fileOutputOptions).withAudioEnabled()
     .start(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),videoRecordEventListener)
```